Docker & Django : How to dockerize my django project and run it in a specific server ip?
I want to dockerize my django project and run it on a specific server says 192.168.156.94:8000. How do I do that? Thank you
Dockerfile
# Use Python 3.12.2 image based on Debian Bullseye in its slim variant as the base image
FROM python:3.12.2-slim-bullseye

# Set an environment variable to unbuffer Python output, aiding in logging and debugging
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1

# Define an environment variable for the web service's port, commonly used in cloud services
ENV PORT 8080

# Set the working directory within the container to /app for any subsequent commands
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the entire current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app/

# Upgrade pip to ensure we have the latest version for installing dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Install dependencies from the requirements.txt file to ensure our Python environment is ready
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Set the command to run our web service using Gunicorn, binding it to 0.0.0.0 and the PORT environment variable
CMD gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:"${PORT}"

# Inform Docker that the container listens on the specified network port at runtime
EXPOSE ${PORT}

command line
docker build -t django-docker-project:latest .

docker run -p 8000:8080 \
--env PIPELINE=production \
--env SECRET_KEY=your_value \
--env DB_NAME=. \
--env DB_USER_NM=. \
--env DB_USER_PW=. \
--env DB_IP=0.0.0.0 \
--env DB_PORT=5432 \
django-docker-project


You can specify an IP address that the host already has in the docker run -p option.  (If you already have a dedicated IP address for this service, consider using the standard HTTP port 80 on the host; -p 192.168.156.54:80:8000.)

@DavidMaze where do I do that tho? In my command line or in my dockerfile?
